# Accessing a remote git repository

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

I have a git repository on a server with IP address XXX.XX.XX.XX and my username is UUU

In my local laptop I am setting up as follows in my .git/config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = UUU@XXX.XX.XX.XX:/home/UUU/repositories/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        receivepack = /usr/bin/git-receive-pack
        uploadpack = /usr/bin/git-upload-pack
```

When I use git push or git pull on my laptop, I get the following error

```
bash: /usr/bin/git-upload-pack: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you specifying receivepack/uploadpack?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove everything you've added to the config file and instead:

```
git remote add origin UUU@XXX.XX.XX.XX:repositories/repo.git
```

As you can see, for user UUU you only need to specify the path within its home.

After this `.git/config` should have an entry like this:

```
[remote "origin"]                                  
        url = UUU@XXX.XX.XX.XX:repositories/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Is git installed on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes. I checked it. And all the executables, git, git-upload-pack and git-receive-pack are in /usr/bin folder which are in the PATH of the remote.

Comment: How does your `.git/config` look now?

Comment: The same as in my original post. I went back.